# PHP: Why does my variable not pass but is within same scope?

Tags: php

So I use a function to check if an account exists. It works nicely except for printing the username when the name is already taken. The functions for the database does run as intended. Just an odd issue with returning the `$username` in the error message.

[Demo Page](http://potion.x10host.com/runescape/)

Try out users Potion which will show being unavailable but states `$username` instead of Potion where as Wolf in this case is available.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $error = "Username cannot be empty.";
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=+¬-]/', $_POST['username']))
    {
        $error = "Username must contain up to 12 characters of A-z letters 0-9 numbers and _.";
    }
    else
    {
        //set the username variable
        $username = $_POST['username'];

        //$username = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/", "", $username);

        //$username=preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z_]/',"",$input)

        //check the runescape website if it exists
        $likelyhood = checkUsername($username);

        //if already exist, update my database 
        if($likelyhood === 28){
            $error = "Congratulations, the username $username appears to be availible!";
            addNewUserToDb($username, 1);
        //if availible, update my database
        }
        if($likelyhood < 28){
            $error = 'Sorry, the username $username is already taken.';
            addNewUserToDb($username, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Variables aren't passed as values, but actual strings in single quotes. Either do `'...username '.$username.' is already...` or use double-quotes instead `"` (which will pass the value of the variable).

Comment: See [PHP documentation on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Comment: Omg. I stayed up stressing the other night over a simple thing... !!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the variable to be interpreted by PHP, you need to put the string in double-quotes:

```
$error = "Sorry, the username $username is already taken.";
```

Answer (score 0):

To interpolate variable in strings, you should use double quotes:

```
$error = "Sorry, the username $username is already taken.";
```

That's what says [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> **Note:** Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

With single quotes, you need to concatenate strings :

```
$error = 'Sorry, the username '.$username.' is already taken.';
```